# Shell Scripting | tr -d '\[\]\_'

Tags: shell, scripting, tr

I am working on a project, and wondering about this command in particular.

```
tr -d '\[\]\_'
```

I am aware that the -d flag deletes all characters matching the criteria of the regular expression inside, but I am unsure of what this expression is saying. Is it deleting all special characters such as '!"[]\ and such? Or is that this command?

```
tr -cd "[[:alnum:]\n ]"
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It deletes all square brackets and underscores.

Comment: For a wordcount application, is there any reason to why this would be necessary?

Comment: Maybe not, as brackets and `_` are not part of words.

Comment: The application of `tr` in word counting is typically something like `tr -sc '[:alnum:]' '[\n*]'`, which uses `-c` for complement, then squeezes any non-alphanumeric characters (i.e., replaces them with just one) and translates them to newlines, so you end up with one word per line. See the [`tr` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tr-invocation.html#tr-invocation) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo "][][_word[]_" | tr -d '\[\]\_'` outputs `word`

The backslashes are escaping the brackets because they're special characters in regex expressions. So this command is just deleting all `[` `]` and `_` characters from the string.

However, `tr -d '[]_'` is enough because tr does not use regex.

Comment: `tr` don't use regex.

Comment: `tr -d '[]_'` would be enough.

Comment: it must deleting all special characters such as '!"[]\

Answer (score 2):

`tr -d '\[\]\_'` removes square brackets and underscores from standard input.

Escaping `[`, `]` and `_` is useless here as these characters have no special meaning with `tr`, they will always be handled as literals.

Note that `tr` **does not use regular expressions**.

From man page :

> The format of the SET1 and SET2 arguments resembles the format of
>   regular expressions; however, they are not regular expressions, only
>   lists of characters.

`[:alnum:]` matches alphanumeric characters (equivalent to `0-9A-Za-z`), so nothing to do with special characters.

Comment: As you pointed out in your comment, `tr` doesn't use regex, so also escaping `[]` is useless: `tr -d '[]_'` would have the same effect. Character ranges don't need square brackets in `tr`, so `tr -d '[a-z]'` is the same as `tr -d '[]a-z'`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for your precious comment. I confused with sed character range syntax. I updated.

Comment: deleting all special characters such as '!"[]\